# jsaTypeError: GoogleTiledMap is not a constructor

Tags: dojo

I define a class and then use it to create a layer.but it has error.but I don't know where it was wrong?

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","esri/SpatialReference","esri/layers/TiledMapServiceLayer","esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils","esri/geometry/Extent",
"esri/layers/TileInfo"],function(declare,SpatialReference,TiledMapServiceLayer,webMercatorUtils,Extent,TileInfo){   
 declare("extras.layer.GoogleTiledMap", [TiledMapServiceLayer], {
    online: false,
    mapStyle: "roadmap",
    constructor: function(a) {
        this.spatialReference = new esri.SpatialReference({
            wkid: 102113
        });
        this.online = a.online || false;
        this.mapStyle = a.mapStyle || "roadmap";
        this.layerId = a.layerId;
        this.suffix = a.suffix || ".png";
        this.tile_url = a.tile_url;
        this.fullExtent = new Extent( - 20037508.342787, -20037508.342787, 20037508.342787, 20037508.342787, this.spatialReference);
        this.initialExtent = new Extent(12557877.595482401, 2596928.9267310356, 12723134.450635016, 2688653.360673282);
        this.tileInfo = new TileInfo({
            "rows": 256,
            "cols": 256,
            "compressionQuality": 0,
            "origin": {
                "x": -20037508.342787,
                "y": 20037508.342787
            },
            "spatialReference": {
                "wkid": 102113
            },
            "lods": [{
                "level": 3,
                "scale": 73957190.948944,
                "resolution": 19567.8792409999
            },
            { ...
```

I use it in html file.

```
require([  
  "esri/map",
  "extras/layer/GoogleTiledMap",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(map,GoogleTiledMap) {
     var layer=new GoogleTiledMap({
            "id": "100",
            "layerId":"GXX_XXXXX",
            "online":false,
            "name": "谷歌电子地图",
            "suffix": "png",
            "tileSize": "256",
            "tileType": "googlemap",
            "mapStyle":"roadmap",
            "tile_url": "127.0.0.1:8080"
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declaring is not sufficient, you need to return it as well. Like below

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",...], function(declare,...){
    return declare([...], {
        //you module here
    });
});
```